Why my express server's api endpoints calls are pending?
I am running an express server that has some REST API endpoints including authentication endpoint: http://localhost:3000/login using jwt (json web token), the server run but when I used postman and several other methods to call the endpoint I keep waiting for the results.
I created an express server in the nodejs environment like so :
require("dotenv").config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
app.use(express.json)


const posts = [
    {
        username: "kyle",
        name: "post1"
    },
    {
        username: "Tyler",
        name: "post2"
    },
]

const authenticateToken = (request, response, next) => {
    const authHeader = request.headers['authorization']
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]

    if(token === null) { return response.sendStatus(401)}

    jwt.verify(token , process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
        if(err) return response.sendStatus(403)

        request.user = user
        next()
    })


}

app.get("/posts", authenticateToken, (request, response) => {

    const filteredPosts = posts.filter(post => post.username === request.user.username)

    response.json(filteredPosts)
})

app.post("/login", (request, response) => {
    //authenticate the user

    const username = request.body.username

    const user = {username: username}
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY)
    response.json({accessToken: accessToken})

})



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`app is lestening on port: 3000`)
})


I run the server successfully using the command : node server.js
and use postman like so :
postman dashboard where the call is made
I expected the request to be treated and I will have the access token as a response, but the request kept pending, I tried using multiple ways to call the api endpoint and I tried to update the nodejs version and creating another project but this didn't work
the rest client vscode approach
here is my package.json file:
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2"
  }
}



Please correct the statement as below, explanation enclosed below.
app.use(express.json) change it to app.use(express.json()));

Please see below an MRE.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/a', express.json(), (req, res) => {
  res.send('route reached /a');
});

app.get('/b', express.json, (req, res) => {
  res.send('route reached /b');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

Test run
node server.js

Request URL 1 :
curl http://localhost:3000/a
Response : route reached /a
Status : Worked as expected

Request URL 2 :
curl http://localhost:3000/b
Response : now response 
Status : the request is hanging...
Reason : Please see below.

express.json()
The above statement does the following things:

express is the Express application object.
express.json() is a static function in Express application which returns a middleware function to parse an incoming request. The issue over here is, app.use(express.json), this statement does not invoke the static function, instead it just passes the static function as such. Therefore it does not meet the intended function. The function must be invoked as this, app.use(express.json()), then it will return the middleware and do the intended function.


Thank you! your answer solved my problem
